# Laravel 5 How to RESTRICT user not able access an Article if the Article STATUS is "Draft"

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

i want to restrict the user not able access the article if the article is not published, and is in draft mode.
For example, an article id is 1, and is in draft mode, when user type url: www.example.com/1, the user still can access it.
Is there a way that i can do it in middleware or use model route binding, so that it will check the Article status. If article is published, user can access, or else if article is draft, user cannot access it.
I try google, but still can find the best way to solve this.

Comment: @Mayank Pandeyz hi, what does it mean saved in? Can explain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you save the modes in the database, you can just check this, **or** in your route **or** in your controller **or** in your view.

I would recommend you doing this in your controller, so you can do something like this;

```
if($article->status == "draft"){
      return redirect()->to('your_url_here');
}
//other code here
```

If you get what I mean?

Comment: hi, thanks for your info. Is that i am able do it in route (web.php)? because in my controller, i had to do it one by one to my function()

Comment: Edit your question and post your code, then I'll look at it to help.

Comment: Hi, my code is long, i'm not able to post here. Just have a quick explaination. In my Controller, i have some functions, that's
```
public function show(){
// show individual publish article details
}
```
```
public function addComment(){
// user can give comment if article is published
}
```
public function storeComment(){
// store user add new comment in published article
}
````
so my question is, is that i have to add below condition in each of my function?
```
if($article->status == "draft"){
      return redirect()->to('your_url_here');
}
```

Comment: No, you just need to add the code that I provided for you in you display, since the rest of your functions need to be protected for other insances. You just want users not be able to "see" your articles that have the draft status, so you only need to check if the article is in draft at the places you want, I assume that would be the `public function show(){}`

Comment: ok, what about if there is the case that, when a user is commenting an article (published status), and at the same time, the editor need to edit the article and change the article status to draft mode. When the user press the submit button, it should not be store, but will pop out notification that this article is now in draft mode. How to do this?

Comment: @JovenDev In the case that, when a user is commenting an article (published status), and at the same time, the editor need to edit the article and change the article status to draft mode, the system will never have such thing hapen. Since, when you comment and the article was put in draft, you just need to add a check if the article has a draft mode (in the function where you submit the comment). Then when the article is in draft mode, you can return an error saying that the article is in draft or that an error occourd. Also please accept the answer if it helped.

Comment: ok, although the answer doesn't seem solve my issue, but thanks for your info